# Get child pages of specified type in Wagtail (or Django)

Tags: django, wagtail

I have the following code to get the child pages of the current one:

```
{% for subpage in self.get_children %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

This is used, for example, to show a gallery of images (each children page have an image).

However, this works fine when only I have one type of children, but, when I try to add another child page (for example to show testimonials), the code above doesn't filter for children type ..so it shows all childs.

I want to know if there is another way to make this work or if my approach is wrong (the use of children pages).

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's often easier to do these kinds of queries in Python code, rather than inside the template. Wagtail page objects provide a `get_context` method where you can set up additional variables to be passed into the template:

```
class GalleryIndexPage(Page):
    # ... field definitions here ...

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        context['image_pages'] = self.get_children().type(ImagePage)
        return context
```

In this code, `type` is one of the methods Wagtail provides for filtering a queryset - see [Page QuerySet reference](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html) for the full list.

With this method defined, you can then access the variable `image_pages` within your template:

```
{% for subpage in image_pages %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can solve this.

First one is to filter your subpages in your view by type, e.g.:

```
page = Page.objects.get(slug='current-page')
pages_with_images = Page.objects.filter(parent=page, type='image')
pages_with_testimonials = Page.objects.filter(parent=page, type='testimonial')
```

Then, in your template, you can separately iterate through `pages_with_images` and `pages_with_testimonials`:

```
{% for subpage in pages_with_images %}
    ...
{% endfor %}

{% for subpage in pages_with_testimonials %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

The second solution is to check type of the subpage in your template:

```
{% for subpage in self.get_children %}
    {% if subpage.type == 'image' %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks :-) ..but I think that @gasman answer is more useful ..thank you anyway !!